# Decode G2A search results (json) to array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Help me to grab name of games from url

This page output json format.
I try to convert it to array, but my code not work. Please help me!

```
$url = 'https://search.g2a.com/items/select?json.wrf=jQuery111003403934023808688_1411464896728&q=NOT+type%3Aindividual+AND+(-type%3Agaming+AND+wholesaleQty%3A%5B1+TO+*%5D+AND+wholesaleMinPrice%3A%5B0+TO+198%5D)&wt=json&start=0&rows=10000&sort=sortOrder+DESC&_=1411464896757';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I tried to load your URI content into jsonlint and it seems to doesn't be a valid json. In addition `print_r()` will not display the value if false (I guess that `json_decode()` return false).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the JSONP parameter `json.wrf` from the URL first:

```
https://search.g2a.com/items/select?q=NOT+type%3Aindividual+AND+(-type%3Agaming+AND+wholesaleQty%3A%5B1+TO+*%5D+AND+wholesaleMinPrice%3A%5B0+TO+198%5D)&wt=json&start=0&rows=10000&sort=sortOrder+DESC&_=1411464896757
```

This will return a proper JSON result.

Comment: Much better answer than mine, +1

Comment: Well observed. +1 OP don't need to write additional code.

Answer (score 1):

The output from that URL (that I get currently starts with):

```
jQuery111003403934023808688_1411464896728({"responseHeader" ...
```

This isn't a pure JSON response, but rather a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) response.

If you're just trying to parse it in PHP, maybe something like:

```
$url = ...;  // Your URL Here
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$pos  = strpos($data, '{');
$data = substr($data, $pos, strlen($data) - $pos - 2);
$json = json_decode($data, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";
```